# Присвоится ли значение всем элементам?

Tags: c#

Мне нужно считать данные, я это делаю. Загвоздка в том, что мне необходимо все данные вычитать в массив, но этот массив, должен быть объявлен как свойство.

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public partial class ChunkIdx1 : ChunkBase
{
    public uint EntryCount { get; set; } = 0;
    public uint EntryMax { get; set; } = 0;
    public Idx1Entry[] Entry { get; set; } = null;
}
```

Запишутся ли данные в массив при переборе его через `foreach`?

Чисто технически, я бы сказал что нет, т.к. это свойство, и оно должно возвращать копию.

Но вопрос остается вопросом.

```
public partial class ChunkIdx1
{
    public override ReadResult Read(Stream stream)
    {
        ReadResult result = BeginRead();
        if (result != ReadResult.Ok)
        {
            return result;
        }

        _ = stream.Read<byte>(8); // skip 8 bytes, fcc and size

        uint count  = (uint) Math.Min(Size, Size.Even() - 8);

        EntryCount = EntryMax = count;

        if (count > 0)
        {
            Entry = new Idx1Entry[count];

            foreach (Idx1Entry t in Entry)
            {
                t.Fcc = stream.Read<uint>();
                t.Flags = stream.Read<uint>();
                t.Position = stream.Read<uint>();
                t.Length = stream.Read<uint>();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Entry = null;
        }

        Debug.WriteLine($"idx1: index entry: {count}", "INFO");

        return ReadResult.Ok;
    }
}
```

Comment: я так понимаю `Idx1Entry` структура?

Comment: @Vasek: Нет, это класс.

Comment: Эм.. ну тогда у вас все сломается(ну если смотреть на текущий код). Создание массива с классами не создает эти классы. Но если ссылки будут про инициализированы, то ни каких копий у вас не будет. Массивы это ссылочный тип.

Comment: `Создание массива с классами не создает эти классы.` Опа, а вот об этом забыл...Т.е. получается при переборе все таки будут ссылки на классы, а не копии?

Comment: Да. Если бы Idx1Entry был структурой, то тогда были бы копии каждого элемента, но не самого массива.

Comment: Понял, запишите ответом.